# How to copy the contents of all subdirectories into one directory, retaining structure and overwriting duplicates with a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories, and files beneath those subdirectories (I'm running Windows 10):

```
C:\MyFolder\Able    
C:\MyFolder\Able\Alpha    
C:\MyFolder\Able\Manifest    
C:\MyFolder\Baker    
C:\MyFolder\Baker\Bravo    
C:\MyFolder\Baker\Manifest    
C:\MyFolder\Charlie    
C:\MyFolder\Charlie\Charlie    
C:\MyFolder\Charlie\Manifest    
C:\MyFolder\Dog    
C:\MyFolder\Dog\Delta    
C:\MyFolder\Dog\Manifest
```

I'd like to create a batch file to copy all subdirectories of `C:\MyFolder` into a specific folder, retaining directory structure and overwriting all duplicate files, but get rid of the first level subdirectory under `C:\MyFolder` like this:

```
C:\MyFolder\Able\*.*             --> C:\NewFolder\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Able\Alpha           --> C:\NewFolder\Alpha\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Able\Manifest        --> C:\NewFolder\Manifest\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Baker                --> C:\NewFolder\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Baker\Bravo          --> C:\NewFolder\Bravo\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Baker\Manifest       --> C:\NewFolder\Manifest\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Charlie              --> C:\NewFolder\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Charlie\Charlie      --> C:\NewFolder\Charlie\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Charlie\Manifest     --> C:\NewFolder\Manifest\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Dog                  --> C:\NewFolder\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Dog\Delta            --> C:\NewFolder\Delta\*.*
C:\MyFolder\Dog\Manifest         --> C:\NewFolder\Manifest\*.*
```

My initial thought was to use the command `"dir /b /s /a:d C:\MyFolder"` to get all the sub-folder names and then use the `xcopy` command to get each line and copy the files over, but I just can't seem to make the connection.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what's wrong with `xcopy /E`?

Comment: Am I asking my question right? Haha. I need to list out all the 1st level subdirectories under C:\MyFolder and copy their contents to the same directory. I could do an `xcopy /E`, but I'd have to find a way to get it to do it for each 1st level subdirectory under C:\MyFolder, and I'm not sure how to do that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion



REM **************************************************

SET source_dir=C:\MyFolder

SET target_dir=C:\NewFolder

REM **************************************************



FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B /A:D "%source_dir%"') DO (
    SET "folder_name=%%G"
    CALL :copy
)


ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO Done^^!
PAUSE
EXIT


:copy
SET "target_folder_name=!folder_name:%source_dir%\=!"
ECHO !target_folder_name! | FINDSTR /C:"\\" >nul && SET "target_folder_name=!target_folder_name:*\=!" || SET "target_folder_name=."

ROBOCOPY "!folder_name!" "%target_dir%\!target_folder_name!" /IT
EXIT /B
```

This basically removes the `C:\MyFolder\*\` from each folder path and the remaining name, path or `.` (if it's a direct sub-folder of `C:\MyFolder`) is added to the `target_dir` path.

---

If a path remains you could also shrink this path to only a name and combine all files of all sub-directories into one sub-folder.

For this, simply replace the `:copy` bit with this:

```
:copy
SET "target_folder_name=!folder_name:%source_dir%\=!"

ECHO !target_folder_name! | FINDSTR /C:"\\" >nul || SET "target_folder_name=."

SET "loop_counter=0"

:loop
SET /A "loop_counter=%loop_counter%+1"
IF %loop_counter%==10 (ECHO Error: Could not copy !folder_name! && EXIT /B)
ECHO !target_folder_name! | FINDSTR /C:"\\" >nul && SET "target_folder_name=!target_folder_name:*\=!" && SET /A "counter=%counter%+1" && GOTO loop

ROBOCOPY "!folder_name!" "%target_dir%\!target_folder_name!" /IT
EXIT /B
```

This adds a loop to remove up to 10 parent directories if any and a loop_counter to prevent an endless loop. Obviously you can have more loops by simply adjusting the `10` in this `IF-Statement`:    `IF %loop_counter%==10`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that would copy `C:\MyFolder\Able` to `C:\adjust\path\Able`, correct? I'm needing to copy `C:\MyFolder\Able\*` to `C:\adjust\path`, and to copy `C:\MyFolder\Baker\*` also to `C:\adjust\path`, and so on in a batch file that does it for each subdirectory in C:\MyFolder".

Comment: @jeff0000 This will copy every folder in `C:\MyFolder` to `C:\adjust\path` and each subfolder will be a subfolder of it's parent folder, thus retaining directory structure. So `C:\MyFolder\Baker\Manifest` will be at `C:\adjust\path\Baker\Manifest`.

Comment: Yep, I'm needing something different then. All files and directory structure need to be copied over to `C:\adjust\path` - basically we need to get rid of the Able / Baker / Charlie / Delta 1st level subdirectories when we copy it to the other directory (with an automated batch script as there are hundreds of directories).

Comment: @jeff0000 Yeah, ok, I'll give it a shot later tonight, shouldn't be too hard. ;)

Comment: @jeff0000 Glad I could help! :)